# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"...тем более(,) что они были знакомы" — отделяется запятой "тем более" или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле здесь возможна двоякая пунктуация, запятая ставится либо перед перед составным союзом, либо перед "что". Но не две, если только первая из них не мотивирована какими-то другими причинами. Впрочем, в нейтральном контексте первый вариант (с запятой перед союзом) предпочтителен.

А вообще, дайте фразу целиком, по контексту оно понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится перед всей конструкцией, а не перед *"что"*. [Пруф.](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_730)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если "тем более что" действительно союз, то запятая, конечно,  ставится перед ним.